# Click Event handler

Tags: gwt, event-handling

when i click on a button the click event handler executes a code . If by mistake(if browser hangs) i click on the button twice the code gets executed twice.i dont want that to happen.
Any suggestions to stop that?

i suppose i should use a schedular or timer but i am not sure

below is the code:

```html
public void onSendButtonClicked() {

        disableButtons();

        eventBus.fireEvent(new SendEmcsDeclarationEvent(getDeclaration(), getMsgType()));
    }
```

Comment: @addullah i dont have any enable functionality in my application, perhaps i need a better solution than this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can - as Abdullah mentioned - disable/enable every widget in GWT with

`widget.setEnable(false)`

and

`widget.setEnable(true)`.

If you want to lock the whole screen, create a modal popup, show it, after the button is pressed and hide it, after the code has finished.

```
public void onSendButtonClicked() {

    myProgessBar.show();

    eventBus.fireEvent(new SendEmcsDeclarationEvent(getDeclaration(), getMsgType()));

    myProgressBar.hide();
}
```

If you are using a async call, you have to hide the progessbar in the callbacks. In this case the finally command might be executed before the callback is executed. In your case it might be a good idea to create a ShowProgressBarEvent and HideProgressbarEvent, so that you can use the progressbar in your whole application.

If your are using a widget library f.e.: GXT, you will find a ProgressBar ready to use.

Hope that helps.

Comment: @ EL Hoss   the disableButtons() function is already disabling the button.The SendEmcsDeclarationEvent function basically sends decleration somewhere but  before the event gets finished by the eventBus another event starts which results in 2 declerations being send with same data.This is the issue that we neeed to resolve

Comment: Where/when do you enable the button?

Comment: As shown in my sample code above, as the send button is clicked the onSendButtonClicked() function is called and in it disableButtons() is called which disables the send button and many other buttons present and finally the decleration is sent.

Comment: I though you disabled the button. How can the button clicked again?

Comment: it gets clicked if the application hangs or internet speed is slow, before getting disabled

Answer (score 0):

The best way I can think of is to enable/disable the button itself so as to make sure that the code in handler is not called again until before the previous call finishes up.

```
public void onSendButtonClicked()
{
    try
    {
        disableButtons();

        eventBus.fireEvent(new SendEmcsDeclarationEvent(getDeclaration(), getMsgType()));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally 
    {
        enableButtons();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When I create a button, I always also add an animating gif (ajaxloader).

When the button is clicked I make the button invisble, the ajaxloader visible.
When the action is done, I make the ajaxloader invisible, and the button visible.

This way the user has some visual feedback that something is happening (what you don't get when disabling the button), and not the entire application gets blocked (as a modal does) which is one of the plus points using ajax.